# JavaScript canvas Snake game

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, event-handling, canvas, snake-game

This is my 3rd JavaScript canvas game. It's basically just snake right now but I am planning on adding some more aspects to it soon. I was wondering if I could get some feedback especially on how I'm checking if the snake crosses itself in the `game` function.

```js
class Block {
  constructor(x, y, w, h, col) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.col = col;
  }

  draw() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb" + this.col;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
}

class Snake {
  constructor(x, y, w, h, col) {
    this.bod = [];
    this.h = h;
    this.w = w;
    this.x = x;
    this.killed = false;
    this.y = y;
    this.spd = 25;
    this.vel = [0, 0];
    this.bod.push(new Block(x, y, w, h, col))
  }

  draw() {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.bod.length; x++) {
      this.bod[x].draw();
    }
  }

  move(tx, ty) {
    this.bod[0].x += tx
    this.bod[0].y += ty;
  }

  grow(pos_x, pos_y) {
    this.bod.push(new Block(pos_x, pos_y, this.w, this.h, "(0, 255, 0)"));
  }

  update() {
    for (var i = this.bod.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      this.bod[i].x = this.bod[i - 1].x;
      this.bod[i].y = this.bod[i - 1].y;
    }
  }
}


function init() {
  start = false;
  canvas = document.getElementById("display");
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  width = canvas.width;
  height = canvas.height;
  player = new Snake(width / 2, height / 2, 25, 25, "(25, 150, 25)")
  food = new Block(Math.floor(Math.random() * 19 + 1) * 25, Math.floor(Math.random() * 19 + 1) * 25, 25, 25, "(255, 0, 0)");
  addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, false);
  menu_loop = setInterval(menu, 10)
}

function menu() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.font = "75px Oswald";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 255, 0)";
  ctx.fillText("Almost Snake!", width / 2, height - (height * 3 / 4));
  ctx.font = "25px Oswald";
  ctx.fillText("space to start", width / 2, height - height / 4);
  if (start) {
    clearInterval(menu_loop);
    game_loop = setInterval(game, 100);
  }
}

function eat() {
  player.grow(food.x, food.y);
  food.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19 + 1) * 25;
  food.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 19 + 1) * 25;
}

function die() {
  clearInterval(game_loop);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
  ctx.textAlign = "center"
  ctx.font = "75px Oswald";
  ctx.fillText("you lose...", width / 2, height / 2);
  setTimeout(function() {
    location.reload();
  }, 2000)
}

function keyDown(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 65:
    case 37:
      player.vel = [-player.spd, 0];
      break;
    case 87:
    case 38:
      player.vel = [0, -player.spd];
      break;
    case 68:
    case 39:
      player.vel = [player.spd, 0];
      break;
    case 83:
    case 40:
      player.vel = [0, player.spd];
      break;
    case 32:
      start = true;
      break;
  }
}

function drawAll() {
  player.draw();
  food.draw();
  ctx.textAlign = "left";
  ctx.font = "25px Oswald";
  ctx.fillText("Length: " + player.bod.length.toString(), 25, 25);
}

function game() {
  player.update();
  player.move(player.vel[0], player.vel[1]);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  for (var i = 1; i < player.bod.length; i++) {
    if (player.bod[0].x == player.bod[i].x && player.bod[0].y == player.bod[i].y) {
      player.killed = true;
    }
  }
  if (player.bod[0].x > width - player.bod[0].w || player.bod[0].x < 0 || player.bod[0].y > height - player.bod[0].h || player.bod[0].y < 0) {
    player.killed = true;
  }
  if (player.bod[0].x == food.x && player.bod[0].y == food.y) {
    eat();
  }
  drawAll();
  if (player.killed) {
    clearInterval(game_loop);
    player.update();
    player.move(player.vel[0], player.vel[1]);
    drawAll();
    setTimeout(die, 1000);
  }
}

window.onload = init;
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');
html {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
}

body {
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black
}

#display {
  border: 3px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Almost Snake!</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="icon" href="AS_ICO.png">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="display" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see `Block` and `Snake` have constructors that both accept five identical parameters. You could consider using inheritance to make a parent-class, which the two child classes inherit from via [`extends`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Sub_classing_with_extends). This would be congruent with the [**D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself principle](https://deviq.com/don-t-repeat-yourself/)

---

Some of the variable are used globally - e.g. `start`, `canvas`, `food`, etc. You could at least limit the scope to an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) or a DOM ready callback.

---

I also see a few places where a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop could be used instead of a traditional `for` loop. For instance, instead of this in `Snake::draw()`:

> ```
> for (var x = 0; x < this.bod.length; x++) {
>   this.bod[x].draw();
> }
> ```

A `for...of` loop could be used to simplify the array indexing:

```
for (const segment of this.bod) {
  segment.draw();
}
```

---

I see that `game_loop` is assigned a timer from calling `setInterval()` in `menu()`, but it is cleared both in `die()` and `game()` - does it really need to be cleared in both places?